# Editing previous character after giving a space after every 4 characters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement IBAN formatter however I want to avoid adding country code at the beginning. So the mask of this IBAN should look like this:

XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX

I achieved this result. However, I am unable to edit previous characters. After typing 4 characters the position of the caret is moving to the left. I also can't edit characters and I must delete the entire number in order to correct the wrong number.

here is my code:

```
           input.addEventListener(e, function(e) {
                var target = e.target, position = target.selectionEnd, length = target.value.length;
                target.value = target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{4})+$)/g, '$1 ');
                console.log("position: " + position)
                console.log("selectionEnd: " + target.selectionEnd)
                console.log("length: " + length)
                console.log("target.length: " + target.value.length)
                target.selectionEnd = position += ((target.value.charAt(position - 1) === ' ' && target.value.charAt(length - 1) === ' ' && length !== target.value.length) ? 1 : 0);
            })
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4r1mc2b9/

**Edit:**

Or maybe is there any option to add a space after first 2 chars and then after every 4?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to give space to string during you typing? Isn't it better to add spaces after the input focus changed?

Comment: Yes, I need to give space during typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following code that add space every 4 characters

```
document.getElementById('iban').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
                    var target = e.target, position = target.selectionEnd, length = target.value.length;
                    target.value = target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(^\d{2})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
                    target.selectionEnd = position += ((target.value.charAt(position - 1) === ' ' && target.value.charAt(length - 1) === ' ' && length !== target.value.length) ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Comment: Yes I can achieve that. But the problem is that at the begining, the first space shoul be after second character and then after every 4 characters.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot for your help.:)